# how to call delegate method, iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Given :

> 1. classA with its delegate
> 2. classB  has a button on it

```
classA.h

@protocol classADelegate <NSObject>
- (void)method:(NSString *) name;
@end
@interface StoreChooser : UIViewController
@end
------------------------------------------------------
classA.m
-(IBAction)buttonCliked{
     // invoke delegate method from classA at here

}

classB.h
@interface classB : UIViewController <classADelegate>
@end

------------------------------------------------------
// Conform delegate of classA
classB.m
- (void)method:(NSString *) name {
```

}
    @end
    ------------------------------------------------------

My goal : I need classB to invoke a method delegate from classA in **buttonClicked** action

**Question** : what should I do to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make sure that we are on the same page :)

If `ClassA` has a delegate `ClassADelegate`. What this means is that when some "event" occurs in `ClassA`, `ClassA` will want to notify some other class via its delegate that the "event" occurred - `ClassB`. `ClassA` will do this via its delegate - `ClassADelegate`.

For this to happen, `ClassB` will have to let `ClassA` know that it will be acting as `ClassA`'s delegate. `ClassB` will have to "conform" to `ClassA`'s protocol by implementing all of the methods listed in the protocol that not marked as @optional.

In code, you could do this:

```
// ClassA's delegate

@protocol ClassADelegate <NSObject>
- (void) didDoSomethingCool:(NSString *) name;
@end

// ClassA definition

@interface ClassA
// We'll use this property to call the delegate.
// id<XXX> means that which ever class is assigned to id MUST conform to XXX
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ClassADelegate> classADelegate; 
- (void) doSomething;
@end

// Class A implementation

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize classADelegate;

- (void) doSomething
{
  // Do cool things here.
  // Now call delegate, in this example, this will be ClassB
  [classADelegate didDoSomethingCool:@"Hello from Class A"];
}
```

Now we need to wire-up `ClassB` so that it can be notified that something happened in `ClassA`:

```
// ClassB definition

@interface ClassB<ClassADelegate>
// ClassB<ClassADelegate> lets the compiler know that ClassB is required to have all the 
// non-optional method that are listed in ClassADelegate. In short, we say that
// ClassB conforms to the ClassADelegate.
{
  ClassA *_classA;
}
@end
```

Now somewhere in `ClassB`'s implementation file we have the following.

```
// ClassB implementation

@implementation ClassB

- (id) init
{
  self = [super init];
  if(self)
  {
    // Just quickly creating an instance of ClassA.
    _classA = [ClassA new];
    // This is were we tell ClassA that ClassB is its delegate.
    _classA.classADelegate = self;
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
  [_classA release];
  [super dealloc]; 
}

- (void) didDoSomethingCool:(NSString *) name
{
  // This is the method that ClassA will be calling via the 
  // [classADelegate didDoSomethingCool:@"Hello from Class A"] method call.
}

@end
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Add an assign property to classA:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<classADelegate> delegate;
```

Then in the viewDidLoad method for classB, call:

```
[myClassAObject setDelegate:self];
```

Then in class A, just call:

```
if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(method:)]) {
       [_delegate method:@"string"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ClassB needs a reference to ClassA. This code is not complete but should help you to understand the relationship you need to create.

classB.h

```
@interface classB: UIViewController <classADelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<classADelegate> delegate;

@end
```

classB.m

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = [[classADelegate alloc] init];
    }
}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked {
    [delegate method:@"name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the delegate object in classA:

```
@interface classA : NSObject
{
    id<classADelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) id<classADelegate> delegate;
```

And synthesize the property:

```
@implementation classA
...

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

And then in the method that needs to call the delegate, you need to test the delegate object and method is valid:

```
- (void)somethingHappened
{
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(method:)])
    {
        [_delegate method:@"Andy"];
    }
}
```

And finally conform to the delegate protocol in class B:

```
@implementation classB
...

- (void)method:(NSString *)name
{
    [self buttonCliked:nil];
}
```