# Delegate doesn't work when trying to segue from UIView's button to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, segue, objc-protocol

I'm trying to programmatically segue to a view controller which is on another storyboard.

To give more details; I've an UILabel and UIButton on my xib where UILabel contains a "Lorem ipsum" and button's type changed custom so that it can be transparent. I've set the button's size to cover all xib file. So when user tap on button, i can create a segue within that button's action.

I know i can't do this directly, so i must have a delegate method which will be invoked from my xib's parent viewcontroller. When i run my project, it keeps falling into else block of Mini.m file's btnClick action.

[image]

I've also done some searching and read some previous posts on SO like following links but somehow couldn't manage to solve the issue. Any ideas what am i missing here?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35583877/1450201

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6169104/1450201

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30508168/1450201

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520042/1450201

Mini.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SelectionProtocol;

@interface Mini : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SelectionProtocol> delegate;

- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender;

@end


@protocol SelectionProtocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void) isClicked;

@end
```

Mini.m

```
#import "Mini.h"

@implementation Mini

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self load];
    }

    return self;
}


- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self load];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)load {
    UIView *view = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:@"Mini" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    [self addSubview:view];
    view.frame = self.bounds;

    //    ui component properties will be set here

}
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(isClicked)]) {
        [self.delegate isClicked];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"AAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    }
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Mini.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SelectionProtocol>

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


-(void) isClicked {
    UIStoryboard *targetStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *targetVC = (UIViewController *)[targetStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetVC animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

---

Edit: I'm using my UIView as a subview of my UIViewCotnroller. Here's a scfeenshot
[image]

---

Edit 2:
Screenshots for my latest changes: (Still can't navigate to SecondViewController)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you setting your `ViewController` as the `delegate` of your view?

Comment: So is there something missing in my ViewController.h file? I thought what i did there was setting it as delegate of the view

Comment: In `ViewController.h` file you are only saying that this class implements the `SelectionProtocol` but you are not telling the instance of `Mini` class that this `ViewController` is its `delegate`.

Comment: oh.. well, how do i do that?

Comment: Is this view a subview of the `ViewController`? Provide a bit more context of your problem. For example, when do you show this view on the screen?

Comment: yes it is. i'm using this uiview to prepare a ui component so that i could use it multiple times in future. my uiview will be shown at the same time as it's parent view controller

Comment: Then when you add the sub view, set the custom view's delegate as self in view controller class.

Comment: i've added screenshot of my ui at the end of my question.

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't know it was something to be set from interface builder. I just dragged a uiview in my viewcontroller and set it's custom class to Mini. Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @jegadeesh i already did that.@Adeel told me that too. Could you refer this github link where i share the project?
 https://github.com/TimurAykutYildirim/demoView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set delegate like this

In ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

Mini *view = [[Mini alloc]init];
 view.delegate = self;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: it didn't work. still falling into else block of Mini.m file's btnClick action

Comment: use  This
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ViewController.isClicked)]) {

Comment: i'm sorry what did you mean by that? i shall change it to what exactly?
i'm using it as in if block but somehow it keeps falling into else block

Comment: Update this Method
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ViewController.isClicked)]) {
        [self.delegate isClicked];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"AAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    }
}

Comment: it want's to add semicolon ":" before the dot of **ViewController.isClicked**
than it gives error

Comment: Try to run  [self.delegate isClicked]; without if condition
 it will work, Than try to debug your if condtion it seems its not confirming that protocol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150693/discussion-between-timur-aykut-yildirim-and-vikram).

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the `ViewController` as the `delegate` of `Mini` view. I assume that the `Mini` view is a subview of `ViewController`. All you need to do is create a reference/pointer of this view in the `ViewController` class and set it as the `delegate` of the View.

1. Create an outlet of your view and connect it with the view placed in the storyboard. Don't forget to change the class of this view to `Mini` in the identity inspector of the Xcode

   ```
   #import "Mini.h"

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController <SelectionProtocol>
       @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet Mini *miniView;
   @end
   ```
2. In the `viewDidLoad` set the `delegate` of this view

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.miniView.delegate = self;
   }
   ```

Comment: quick question, have you noticed anything else odd? i did try your solution but couldn't navigate to second vc

Comment: Did you connect the `IBOutlet` with the view placed in the storyboard? Also change the class of this view to `Mini` in the identity inspector.

Comment: i created an outlet of the view component placed in my viewcontroller to ViewController.h file then called in viewDidLoad

Comment: added 3 screenshots at the end of my question

Comment: [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Bgmw9gPOgI) a short video on how to connect IBOutlet to storyboard.

Comment: thanks but as you can see from the last screenshot, i know how to create an outlet. if you could just examine the last 3 screenshots, i think you will see what's what in my code. in fact, let me share it with you by bitbucket

Comment: Where is your button on the storyboard? Did you connect it to `- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150696/discussion-between-timur-aykut-yildirim-and-adeel).

Comment: my button is on the xib. let's continue in chat. can't keep writing long comments

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a instance who conform to the protocol as the delegate.`object.delegate = self`.